# How can I make my app accept certain photos file extensions?

Tags: swift, types, format, photo, file-extension

I want my app to accept certain image extensions(png, jpg,.....)
otherwise, it should show an error message.

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    
    @IBAction func didTapCamera(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true)
      }
    
}
    extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage{
                imageView.image = image
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
}
```

I couldn't find any subject or code about it, I don't know why we need to request certain extensions, but it's required in my collage project.

Comment: Why do you need to limit the image based on extension? You can accept any image. You can then convert the selected image to either PNG or JPG as needed. Very simple.

Comment: Unrelated but replace `info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")]` with `info[.editedImage]`.

Comment: Use [UTType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype)?